# Simple chat console app

Tags: java, multithreading, console, socket, chat

I wanted to practice using sockets and multithreading. This is simple code where I start a `Server` and connect to it via `Client` and chat between them.

`Server` class:

```
public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4545);
        SocketEnhancer socketEnhancer = new SocketEnhancer(serverSocket.accept());
    }
}
```

`Client` class:

```
public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        SocketEnhancer socketEnhancer = new SocketEnhancer(new Socket("localhost",4545));
    }
}
```

`SocketEnchancer`:

```
public class SocketEnhancer {

    DataReceiver dataReceiver;
    DataSender dataSender;
    Socket socket;

    public SocketEnhancer(Socket socket){
        this.socket = socket;
        dataReceiver = new DataReceiver(this);
        dataSender = new DataSender(this);
        new Thread(dataSender).start();
        new Thread(dataReceiver).start();
    }

    public Socket getSocket() {
        return socket;
    }
}
```

`DataReceiver`:

```
public class DataReceiver implements Runnable {

    SocketEnhancer socketEnhancer;

    public DataReceiver(SocketEnhancer socketEnhancer) {
        this.socketEnhancer = socketEnhancer;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socketEnhancer.getSocket().getInputStream()));
            while (true) {
                String readLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
                if(readLine != null){
                    System.out.println("Data received: " + readLine);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

`DataSender`:

```
public class DataSender implements Runnable {

    SocketEnhancer socketEnhancer;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public DataSender(SocketEnhancer socketEnhancer) {
        this.socketEnhancer = socketEnhancer;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(socketEnhancer.getSocket().getOutputStream());
            while(true) {
                String readLine = scanner.nextLine();
                printWriter.write(readLine + System.lineSeparator());
                printWriter.flush();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Any comments and criticism is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SocketEnhancer socketEnhancer = new SocketEnhancer(serverSocket.accept());
```

Currently, this is a not very advanced chat application as you can only have one client. It'll be a 1-1 conversation. It will just be one server and one client talking to each other. You can run the `serverSocket.accept()` in a loop to allow you to have more clients. The server then needs to loop through all the available clients (so you need some `Collection` for those) and then send the incoming message to all clients.

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4545);
    SocketEnhancer socketEnhancer = new SocketEnhancer(serverSocket.accept());
}
```

You don't need to declare the `socketEnhancer` variable as you're not using it any more in the method. The compiler should give you an unused variable warning here.

---

```
DataReceiver dataReceiver;
DataSender dataSender;
Socket socket;
```

private final, private final, private final. All of those should be `private final`.

The same goes for all your fields in other classes.

---

```
dataReceiver = new DataReceiver(this);
dataSender = new DataSender(this);
```

So you create a `DataReceiver` and a `DataSender` and give them both the `SocketEnhancer` reference? Let's see how you use that in the classes then.

```
new InputStreamReader(socketEnhancer.getSocket().getInputStream())
```

and

```
socketEnhancer.getSocket().getOutputStream()
```

You send the entire `socketEnhancer` only so that you can use the `getSocket` method on it once to create the OutputStream. It is much better to **give them the `InputStream` / `OutputStream` directly.** This is what is called **Tell, Don't Ask!**

**When possible, don't give your classes an object they can ask about something, give them what they need directly.**

---

```
public class DataSender implements Runnable {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    ...
```

I would recommend moving the `Scanner` to your `main` method, and letting your `main` method call a method on your `SocketEnhancer` object whenever it wants to send a message. The `SocketEnhancer` can then call a method on `dataSender` to perform the sending.

---

Overall, I have to say that your code is quite clean and easy to read. Good job.